# Issue with custom pinpad component

Tags: android, custom-controls

I created a custom pin pad component. The components are made of native  Edit text . My custom component is working fine. My problem is when I have this component at the end of the page and when I try to input the value, the virtual keyboard comes up but my component got hidden.

Note : I have used  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in my manifest and same thing is working fine when i use edit text component alone

Comment: the posts on this SO question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard